# subprocess.communicate() won't supply input to Popen calling ssh via git

Tags: python, git, subprocess

I am using python 2.7 so I am unable to use what I think would work (subprocess.check_ouput() with input argument) and I am trying to pass the string 'yes' to the Popen object. Here is my code.

```
def clone(ssh_url):
    sub_list = ['git', 'clone', ssh_url]
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(sub_list, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                           universal_newlines=True)
    output, err = cmd.communicate(input='yes')
        print output
        if err is not None:
            print err

ssh_url = 'git@gitlab.com:User1/test-work.git'
clone(ssh_url)
```

So I am trying to clone a gitlab project. I haven't used the ssh key on this machine before so I am receiving a message saying what the value of the ECDSA key fingerprint is and whether or not I want to continue connecting (yes/no). 
I want to pass 'yes' to this selection when it is presented, however, the input I supplied `communicate()` is not received and I get a `Host Key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository` error from git.

Is anyone aware of a way to make this work? Is communicate() blocking? I tried using the threading example here, [Use subprocess.communicate() to pipe stdin without waiting for process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759254/use-subprocess-communicate-to-pipe-stdin-without-waiting-for-process), in the accepted response but that did not work either.

Comment: Is the line `output, err = ...` mis-indented? If so, please fix.

Comment: yes it was. thanks.

Comment: Passwords (and other sensitive/authentication/security-related content) aren't read from stdin, they're read from the TTY directly. If that weren't true, and you tried to run `ssh somehost 'bash -s' <somescript` it would try to read the first line of the script as the answer if it needed to prompt, instead of... well... letting the user actually write an answer.

Comment: Don't try to use `communicate()` to answer that prompt -- rather, tell SSH not to ask at all. See [Passing SSH options to `git clone`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772190/passing-ssh-options-to-git-clone). This also prevents you from inadvertently answering "yes" to a different prompt than the one you want.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the comment and explanation. Makes perfect sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intentional, desired behavior from SSH. It's not anything you're doing wrong in your Python -- rather, SSH intentionally doesn't use stdin to collect answers to security-related prompts (which ensures that its stdin is passed through to the remote command, rather than consumed by SSH itself).

```
git_env = os.environ.copy()
git_env['GIT_SSH_COMMAND'] = 'ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
cmd = subprocess.Popen(sub_list,
  stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
  universal_newlines=True, env=git_env)
```